# Remove max (or min) from collection using Java8 streaming API

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have little problem with code design that use new streaming API from Java 8. I would like to learn new things and one of the task is:

Reject max and min from list. List not contains duplicates.

Looks simple? Nope... My code:

```
  List<Integer> ranges = Lists.newArrayList(new Range(1, 15));
        List<Integer> collect = ranges.stream()
                .filter(x -> x != ranges.stream()
                        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                        .max()
                        .getAsInt())
                .filter(x -> x != ranges.stream()
                        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                        .min()
                        .getAsInt())

                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        assertThat(collect).hasSize(13);   // OK
        assertThat(collect).isEqualTo(Lists.newArrayList(new Range(2,14)));   // OK
```

this code is good (if only we dont have duplicates of min/max, but this is not a core problem here) but problem is that I use here three streams. First is main stream, second to remove max and third to remove min. 
Is there any possibility to do this task in one stream?

//edit:
Very primitive Scala version:

```
val list = List.range(1, 15).sortWith(_>_).tail.reverse.tail
```

with additional sort because we could have shuiffeled list.

Comment: Uhm, doing this without streams is even more simple... But OK, this is an exercise, so...

Comment: You can't do it with one stream as long it is unsorted. You need to resolve min and max beforehand. If your stream is sorted you can do it with with `.filter(x -> x != ranges.get(0)).filter(x -> x != ranges.get(ranges.size()-1))`

Comment: I think that the Scala version can not be compared to the Java version. The Scala approach (sorting and removing the first and the last element) is completely different to the Java approach (computing min and max, and filtering the stream)

Comment: @Marco13 I know but it's a nice example what I want to get.

Comment: Shouldn't something like `List<Integer> collect = ranges.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()).subList(1, ranges.size()-1);` then be an option? It's at least closer to the Scala approach...

Comment: @Koziołek please keep in mind that sorting the collection and removing the first/last element will be in O(n*log(n)) while calculating min/max and then eliminating these with a stream will be O(n) (both worst case)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excluding extrema from HashSet with a Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923505/excluding-extrema-from-hashset-with-a-stream)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is not very efficient, but I think it follows your requirements - it does what you want and it is in one single *pipeline* - one single sequence of bulk data operations, how Java 8 calls it.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

Stream<Integer> ranges = Stream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(15);
List<Integer> collect = ranges
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) // sort the stream from the highest to the smallest
    .skip(1)                           // discards 1 element from the beginning
    .sorted()                          // sort the stream from the smallest to the highest
    .skip(1)                           // discards 1 element from the beginning
    .collect(Collectors.toList())     
    ;
```

But, as fge suggested and Marco13 wrote in their comment below your question, it would be better and much more efficient just to sort the stream, terminate the pipeline to a list and then remove the first and the last member :P Or even faster without sort - go through all the elements, find min and max, remember their position and then remove them.

Answer (score 29):

Don't forget `Collection.removeIf`.  You can compute min and max, and then do:

```
list.removeIf(x -> x == min || x == max);
```

(This also deals well with duplicates.)

Comment: Brilliant. I had no idea this existed!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have shown, Java can do this just fine. To provide an alternative to the other answers, you can make this even more concise if you know the size of the data set beforehand. To match your Scala version, here is the essentially the same thing in Java.

```java
IntStream
   .rangeClosed(1,15)
   .sorted()               //Sorts the contents
   .limit(dataSetSize - 1) //Keeps all except the last element
   .skip(1)                //Removes the min element
   .boxed()
   .toList()
   ;
```

That gives you this.

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

You can replace the `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 15)` with any `Stream<T extends Comparable<T>>`. As long as `T extends Comparable<T>`, then this strategy works.

And if `T` does not implement `Comparable<T>`, just provide your own `Comparator<T>`.

```java
record Foo(int value) {}

Stream
   .of(new Foo(1), new Foo(7), new Foo(3), new Foo(2), new Foo(6), new Foo(4), new Foo(5))
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Foo::value))
   .limit(dataSetSize - 1)
   .skip(1)
   .toList()
   ;
```

That gives you this.

```
[Foo[value=2], Foo[value=3], Foo[value=4], Foo[value=5], Foo[value=6]]
```