# Excluding extrema from HashSet with a Stream

Tags: java, performance, java-8, java-stream

I've been experimenting with Java 8 streams, is this is best way to remove the min and max scores.

```
private final Set<MatchScore> scores = new HashSet<>(10);

. . .

public double OPR() {
    return scores.stream()
            .mapToDouble(MatchScore::getScore)
            .filter((num) -> { //Exclude min and max score
                return num != scores.stream()
                                    .mapToDouble(MatchScore::getScore)
                                    .max().getAsDouble() 
                        && 
                       num != scores.stream()
                                    .mapToDouble(MatchScore::getScore)
                                    .min().getAsDouble();
            })
            .average().getAsDouble();
}
```

Comment: Note, this approach is O(N^2) since, for each element in the scores set, it makes two full passes over the set to compute the max and min.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simpler approach would be:

```
return scores.stream()
        .mapToDouble(MatchScore::getScore)
        .sorted()
        .skip(1)
        .limit(scores.size() - 2)
        .average().getAsDouble();
```

Note: that works because elements in a set are unique - with a list there could be more than one element equal to the min or max score.

---

Performance wise*, the skip/limit is significantly faster on a small set of 10 elements (the Mean column shows the average time taken by a sample call, in nanoseconds):

```
Benchmark                      Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
c.a.p.SO22923505.maxMin        avgt         5     6996.190      284.287    ns/op
c.a.p.SO22923505.skipLimit     avgt         5      479.935        4.547    ns/op
```

<sub>*using jmh - and here is [the source code for the tests](https://bitbucket.org/assylias/performance/src/627163f1c37fb1e80eae2649d8d3a9c4b4aaeba6/src/main/java/com/assylias/performance/SO22923505.java).</sub>

Comment: This is indeed faster than the OP's but it's still O(n log n) because of the sorting.

Comment: +1 for benchmarking using jmh and for posting the code.

Answer (score 4):

One can use `DoubleSummaryStatistics` to collect the required information in a single pass over the data, and then subtract out the minimum and maximum:

```
@GenerateMicroBenchmark
public double summaryStats() {
    DoubleSummaryStatistics stats =
        scores.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Double::doubleValue));

    if (stats.getCount() == 0L) {
        return 0.0; // or something
    } else {
        return (stats.getSum() - stats.getMin() - stats.getMax()) / (stats.getCount() - 2);
    }
}
```

Adding this code to assylias' benchmark code gives me the following results. Although my machine is slower overall, the relative performance of using `DoubleSummaryStatistics` over a single pass is faster.

```
Benchmark                         Mode   Samples         Mean   Mean error    Units
c.a.p.SO22923505.maxMin           avgt         5     9629.166     1051.585    ns/op
c.a.p.SO22923505.skipLimit        avgt         5      682.221       80.504    ns/op
c.a.p.SO22923505.summaryStats     avgt         5      412.740       85.372    ns/op
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the job without having to make multiple passes through the stream, or sorting it:

```
private static class ScoreData {
    public double min, max, sum;
    public int count;
    public ScoreData() {
        min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
    }
    public void add(double d) {
        if (d < min)
            min = d;
        if (d > max)
            max = d;
        sum += d;
        count++;
    }
    public void combine(ScoreData m) {
        if (m.min < min)
            min = m.min;
        if (m.max > max)
            max = m.max;
        sum += m.sum;
        count += m.count;
    }
}

private static ScoreData getScoreData(DoubleStream ds) {
    return ds.collect(ScoreData::new, ScoreData::add, ScoreData::combine);
}
```

This works for any `DoubleStream`.  Now you can get the average excluding the extrema like

```
ScoreData sd = getScoreData(scores.stream().mapToDouble(MatchScore::getScore));
double answer = (sd.sum - sd.min - sd.max) / (sd.count - 2);
```

assuming that `sd.count > 2`.

**EDIT:** Looks like I just reinvented the wheel!  Stuart has a better solution using a class that already exists in the JDK.

Comment: Good insight! +1. But in fact the collector you wrote is present in the JDK already; it's called `DoubleSummaryStatistics`.